# AngularJS grid iterate inner array of an array

Tags: angularjs, grid

I am new to angularjs, i have a JSON file where, i have set of values and i read this in my grid table and displaying it. Consider the below JSON records,

```
{
    "result" : [
    {
       "ID": "001",
       "tables" : ["ABC","AXD"]
    },
    {
        "ID": "002",
       "tables" : ["ABC","AXD"]
    },
    {
        "ID": "003",
       "tables" : ["ABC","AXD"]
    },
    {
        "ID": "004",
       "tables" : ["ABC","AXD"]
    },
    {
        "ID": "005",
       "tables" : ["ABC","AXD"]
    }
    ]
}
```

Here totally five records are there, in each record i have a field called "tables", in this field i have array of values, here while displaying this in my view table, i could able to display only 5 rows, but i want to display 10 rows as below.

```
ID  Table
---------
1   ABC
1   AXD
2   ABC
2   AXD
3   ABC
3   AXD
4   ABC
4   AXD
5   ABC
5   AXD
```

**How currently disaplying**

```
ID       Table
----------------
1   ["ABC","AXD"]
2   ["ABC","AXD"]
3   ["ABC","AXD"]
4   ["ABC","AXD"]
5   ["ABC","AXD"]
```

I am using grid code as below url

http://angular-data-grid.github.io/demo/bootstrap/#!?page=1

Comment: you need to do your own implementation of data grid

Comment: Agreed.. i done my own implementation by changing the json structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep the json value into json file and then use this

```
$http.get('/result.json').success(function (data) {

            $scope.result = data.result;
            $scope.NewTable=[];
            for(i=0;i<$scope.result.length;i++){
                var ID=$scope.result[i].ID;


                for(j=0;j<$scope.result[i].tables.length;j++){
                    var Value=$scope.result[i].tables[j];

                    var obj={};
                    obj.ID=ID;
                    obj.Table=Value;
                    $scope.NewTable.push(obj);

                }
            }


    });
```

Comment: Something similar to the above i found the solution, but exactly not this. i have processed my 5 json records to 10 json record and stored it into gridOption.data.push(all) and made use of this in grid table

Answer (score 0):

Just used nested ng-repeat for this. For you example you need two ng-repeat directive to achieve your result

One for iterating each object.
second for iterating array in each object

Comment: we can use two ng-repeat, but the problem is pagination issues will come in grid options. since $index will not consider inner arrays as seperate row.